# gSOAP + Java WS

Tags: java, c, web-services, gsoap

Does gSOAP support complex types relative to Java. i.e, I have a java object with HashMap and ArrayList in my webservices, now when I convert that in to pure C code would I be able to pass and retrieve parameters from/to C code to/from Java code,. Please Suggest!